# My pothos leaves have cracks. What could be the reason?

Tags: houseplants

[image]

I propagated pothos in water. The leaves are cracked and crippled. Please see picture. What could be the reason? Any disease? If so which one and what’s the remedy?

Comment: My guess is they are not getting any nutrients , i propagated pothos , i put them in water and once they started rooting i put them in soil and they are doing well but the one which i left in water it snt long roots but after two weeks it started showing symptoms that it is going to next world. I tossed it in trash bin.

Comment: It does look like physical damage, but under magnification, its not possible to see the leaves clearly. Just check beneath the leaves to make sure there's no  invaders under there (you miight need a magnifying glass)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably nothing to worry about, no pest, no disease, just a mechanical bend or twist or bump. Keep in mind that when the growing tip is young the tissues are very fragile, wrapped in a tight bundle. Any bump or knock could fracture the leaf, and since the cells are so young they will dry out at the edge, causing odd shapes and marks. Provided there is a growing tip (not immediately visible from your photo), once the cutting is growing freely in soil and able to explore its environment regular leaves will appear and the initial few leaves will have done their job and forgotten. Give it a week or two to show you what it can do, it might surprise you.